# Does a sahuagin's Blood Frenzy trait give advantage on Spiritual Weapon's attack roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters

[Sahuagin](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/sahuagin) have the Blood Frenzy trait:

> The sahuagin has advantage on melee attack rolls against any creature that doesn't have all its hit points.

If a Sahuagin casts [*spiritual weapon*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spiritual%20Weapon), does the melee spell attack from  qualify for Blood Frenzy?

Comment: Yes a Sahuagin is casting the spell and wondering if it gets advantage

Comment: Is this a homebrew monster? The standard Sahuagin (as linked) doesn't include spellcasting. If so, do you have any other details that may impact an answer?

Answer (score 14):

### Yes, the Sahuagin gets advantage

*Spiritual weapon* states (**emphasis** mine):

> When **you** cast the spell, **you** can make a melee spell attack against a creature within 5 feet of the weapon.
>
> [...]
>
> As a bonus action on your turn, **you** can move the weapon up to 20 feet and repeat the attack.

It is clear that the caster is making the attack despite the fact that the weapon may be far away from the character itself.

[A melee spell attack is a melee attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112213/is-a-melee-spell-attack-also-a-melee-attack), so it satisfies the requirement for Blood Frenzy if the target has missing hit points.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

If the trait were limited to weapon attacks, it would say melee weapon attacks. As it specifies only melee attacks, it applies to melee weapon attacks and melee spell attacks, such as Spiritual Weapon.