# Does the Absorb Elements spell combine with a sorcerer's Distant Spell metamagic option?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, attack, metamagic

According to the answers to the question "[Is a melee spell attack also a melee attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112213/45591)", a melee spell attack **is** a melee attack. Meaning that if I were to cast *absorb elements* after being hit by a *fire bolt*, I can add 1d6 fire damage to my next *shocking grasp*.

As a sorcerer, could I combine this with the Distant Spell [Metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic) option?

Using a sorcery point allows me to give a touch-range spell a range of 30 feet instead. Is *shocking grasp* now a melee spell attack with a range of 30 feet, and therefore eligible for the extra damage granted by *absorb elements*?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Yes, because the spell is still a melee spell

Looking at [Sage Advice](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/01/17/if-you-use-distant-spell-on-a-touch-spell-is-it-still-considered-a-melee-spell-attack/) (see quote below) the Distant Spell Metamagic just adds a range of 30ft as you've said, but the spell is still considered a melee spell, thus a melee attack so you can add the 1d6 fire damage to it.

> **Ironforged**
>   *@JeremyECrawford* If you use distant spell on a touch spell like shocking grasp, is it still considered a melee spell attack? I know steel wind strike is a spell that melee spell attack with a range of 30ft, are distant touch spells like that?
>
> **Jeremy Crawford** Distant Spell changes range. It doesn't change anything else about a spell. #DnD

Comment: Note that [Crawford's tweets are no longer official rulings as of the 2019 Sage Advice Compendium](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140221/with-the-2019-sage-advice-compendium-release-are-jeremy-crawfords-tweets-consi). SageAdvice.eu is just the name of a third-party site that compiles designer tweets. You may want to update your answer accordingly, and support it by citing the rules.

Answer (score 15):

## Yes.

From the PHB (emphasis mine) :

> **Most** creatures have a 5-foot reach and can thus attack targets within 5 feet of them when making a melee attack. Certain creatures (typically those larger than Medium) have melee attacks with a **greater reach than 5 feet**, as noted in their descriptions.

The distance doesn't seem to matter, as long as you have the reach, you can make a melee attack. Distant spell gives you the reach, Shocking Grasp makes you do a melee attack, thus the effect triggers.

Comment: Another example is Bigby's Hand: you magically control an object that can make a Melee Spell Attack on your behalf.  It might make sense to think of Distant Spell as applying Touch spells through a magic object that touches the target, maybe instead of the spell going out through your fingers and becoming a melee attack with huge reach.