# Does Swashbuckler's Fancy Footwork apply if the attack was made with Booming Blade?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, opportunity-attack, rogue

The Roguish Archetype Swashbuckler (SCAG/XGtE) has the following feature:

> **Fancy Footwork**
>
> When you choose this archetype at 3rd level, you learn how to land a strike and then slip away without reprisal. During your turn, if you make a melee attack against a creature, that creature can't make opportunity attacks against you for the rest of your turn.

The cantrip Booming Blade (SCAG) says the following:

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell's range, otherwise the spell fails.

**First Question:**

Does Fancy Footwork apply (no OA from the attacked creature) if you attacked it with Booming Blade (or Green Flame Blade)?

**Second Question:**

More generally, since it does not specify a weapon attack, does Fancy Footwork apply to melee spell attacks as well?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Yes, Fancy Footwork applies in these instances

Your reading is correct. To trigger [Fancy Footwork](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#Swashbuckler) all you need to do is:

> make **a melee attack** against a creature

The cantrips [Booming Blade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/booming-blade) and [Green-Flame Blade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade) use identical wording when they say:

> you must make **a melee attack** with a weapon against one creature

So both Booming Blade and Green-Flame Blade do trigger Fancy footwork. Making a melee attack [does not require the Attack action to have been taken](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105781/40921).

By the same reasoning, any melee spell attack (such as [Thorn Whip](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thorn-whip)) will also trigger Fancy Footwork - [a melee spell attack is still a type of melee attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112213/40921). It makes no difference for Fancy Footwork that that melee attack has been made via the Cast a Spell action rather than by an Attack action.